# Local variable/for loop in jTemplates

Tags: jquery, jtemplates

Is it possible to create a local variable or a for loop (instead of foreach) in a jtemplate? I want to give unique id's to the HTML elements and need a counter or something. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `$index`

```
$index - index of the element in the table
$iteration - ID of the iteration (the next number begins from 0)
$first - is this the first iteration?
$last - is this the last iteration?
$total - the total number of iterations
```

ex

```
{#foreach $T.Rows as row}
  $T.row$index
{#/for}
```

read http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/45759/jQuery-jTemplates-Grid

Comment: Worked prefectly. Thank you very much!